# Convert string to javascript array

Tags: json

I am trying to convert String to Javascript array by using following functions but none of them seems working for me .
Functions that I have used for conversion are as follows :-

1. `var array = angular.fromJson(String);`
2. `var array = JSON.parse(String);`

Can any body tell me how to do conversion of string to JavascriptArray in angularjs.

Here is my String :-

```html
"[
      [new Date("2015/08/04 16:33:05"), 26.2, 15.0, 36.0],
      [new Date("2015/08/04 16:38:05"), 26.0, 15.0, 36.0],
      [new Date("2015/08/04 16:43:05"), 26.2, 15.0, 36.0],
      [new Date("2015/08/04 16:48:05"), 26.1, 15.0, 36.0],
      [new Date("2015/08/04 16:53:05"),
        26.2, 15.0, 36.0
      ],
      [new Date("2015/08/04 16:58:05"), 26.2, 15.0, 36.0],
      [new Date("2015/08/04 17:03:05"), 26.3, 15.0, 36.0],
      [new Date("2015/08/04 17:08:05"), 26.3, 15.0, 36.0],
    ]"
```

Thanks

Comment: Your example would appear to not be JSON at all.

Comment: Its not your json string, its already a javascript array.

Comment: i forget to mention my Data between " " ....its my json string , like "value":"[[ new Date(\"2015/08/06 16:37:05\"), 28.8, 15.0, 36.0],[ new Date(\"2015/08/06 16:42:05\"), 28.8, 15.0, 36.0],]"

Comment: What is your exact string. before convert?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(String);
var array = obj["value"];
```

Comment: Hey Cesarluis can you please tell me how to extract javascript array from this strng value :-  "value":"[[ new Date(\"2015/08/06 16:37:05\"), 28.8, 15.0, 36.0],[ new Date(\"2015/08/06 16:42:05\"), 28.8, 15.0, 36.0],]"

Comment: This is not a valid JSON string. If strval equals what you said, wrap it in "{" and "}" (e.g. objstrval = "{" + strval + "}") and then use what @cesarlius says - JSON.parse(objstrval)

Comment: you might want to read about what is valid JSON, e. g.  here http://www.fizerkhan.com/blog/posts/JSON-is-not-Javascript-Object.html

Comment: Thanks for your replies but still its not working for me ..i tried it by two different ways one is :- var ObjStrValue = "{" + graphData + "}"
    var array =angular.fromJson(ObjStrValue);
    alert(array); And another as mentioned by @igor R i.e var ObjStrValue = "{" + graphData + "}"
    var array =JSON.parse(ObjStrValue);
    alert(array);

Comment: new Date is not a valid JSON, @Ashwin K below is right in both things - eval would help but is bad practice. See a better solution through Function constructor here http://dfkaye.github.io/2014/03/14/javascript-eval-and-function-constructor/

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not a JSON string, using `eval(string)` method you may get desired output.

But people say *eval is evil* : [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Demo: [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/55uuzkod/)

Updated: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/55uuzkod/1/)

Comment: Using eval(String) , I am not getting desire result. Here is my full string which I am getting in Api response:

http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/view/ro.p2NNzWX8$g$/latest

and is jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/9hWQ6/14/

Answer (score 0):

Your array is in string format with unevaluated date expression. just evaluate it as below and you get your array.

```
 var array = eval("[ [new Date('2015/08/04 16:33:05'), 26.2, 15.0, 36.0],  [new Date('2015/08/04 16:43:05'), 26.2, 15.0, 36.0] ]");
```

Comment: Please check my new thread :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912460/ng-init-in-ng-repeat-shows-only-the-last-item-in-dygraph